# Get data from an Edit Text box

Tags: excel, vba

I want to grab data from an Edit Text box from other workbooks and insert it into a single worksheet in a different workbook.

```vb
Sub TransferCompanyNames()
    for(int i = 0; i < 479; i++){
        variable = Workbooks.Open Range(//Column A with index i);
        //column a contains a link to the workbook C:/Users/.../Documents/file.xlsx
        //grab data from Edit Text Box and insert into current sheet at column A with index i
    }
End Sub
```

I understand that this isn't the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Sub TransferCompanyNames()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetSheet = Workbooks("ChangeToYourWorkbookName").Worksheets("ChangeToYourSheetName")
    For i = 1 To 480
        Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(Range("A" & i).Value)
        TargetSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters(1, _
                                           ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.Count).Text
        SourceBook.Close False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after. Thanks so much. I'm gonna give it a go now

Comment: This looks to be working perfect. However it appears I have some errors in some of my workbooks. I'm getting an error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method. I've done a little digging and it looks like some of the edit text boxes in some workbooks are missing. How would I go about checking if the value is undefined/ null in vba?

Comment: I ended up using On Error Resume Then and the script ran without a hitch. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, my code simply takes whatever the first shape is on the sheet, which has a risk if anything other than a textbox happens to be the "top" shape on the sheet. We could expand the code to check all shapes and only do the textboxes, but perhaps that is overkill in this situation